# Calculating Limits with the use of L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't figure out the next equation. The answer is negative infinity, but i don't know how to get there by using L'Hospital.
The equation is:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin(2x)}{x^3}$$

Comment: Which problem do you run into when you try to use L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: If i get the derivative of the function i get: $$ -((2x+2xcos(2x)-3sin(2x))/x^4 $$

Comment: Actually, you are supposed to get the derivative of the numerator and the derivative of the denominator, **not** the derivative of the quotient.

Comment: Router: Have a look at examples https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to use the following standard limit (which can also been easily shown using L'Hospital):

- $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}=\frac{1}{2}$

\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin(2x)}{x^3}
& \stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim} & \frac{1-2\cos(2x)}{3x^2} \\
& = & \underbrace{4\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{3(2x)^2}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}} -\underbrace{\frac{\cos(2x)}{3x^2}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\infty}\\
&\stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}& -\infty
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

Using $\sin x $～ $x-x^3/6$, it is simple to see that the limit diverges  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}=\frac{x-\sin 2x}{x^3}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x-2x+8x^3/6}{x^3}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=-\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

To apply L'hopital, it doesn't seem necessary to apply any identities to the trig part

$$\frac{x - \sin(2x)}{x^3}$$

differentiate top and bottom (independently)

$$\frac{1 - 2\cos(2x)}{3x^2}$$

then clearly as x tends to zero, the numerator becomes negative 1, nut the denominator becomes zero - giving you your result of a tending to negative infinity

Comment: You cannot say the 'numerator becomes $-1$', since $\cos(2x)$ is an oscillating function, so it does not converge to anything at negative infinity.

Comment: in his question, he has limit as x tends to zero, not infinity - if it was infinity, the squeeze or sandwich rule would work great

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I couldn't see the $0$ from the computer screen :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin 2x}{x^3}&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-2\sin x\cos x}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin x+\sin x-2\sin x\cos x}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}+\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x(1-2\cos x)}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{3x^2}+\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-2\cos x}{x^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{-1}{0^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{6}+(-\infty)\\
&=-\infty.
\end{align*}

Can you understand me?